# MomentJS returns obscure date for 1st of month

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm having a small problem with MomentJS returning a nonsense date. I am attempting to set the date to the first of a given month and year. I have tried the following:-

```
var _year = 2015;
var _month = 10;
var _dateString = _year.toString() + '-' + _month.toString() + '-1';
var _date = moment(_dateString, 'YYYY-MM-D');
console.log('_date', _date.format('dddd, do MMMM YYYY'));
```

This gives `Thursday, 4th October 2015` as the `_date`. Which doesn't exist.  I tried using `.set()` and `.date()`, both give the same result:-

```
var _date = moment(_dateString, 'YYYY-MM-D').set('date', 1);
> Thursday, 4th October 2015

var _date = moment(_dateString, 'YYYY-MM-D').date(1);
> Thursday, 4th October 2015
```

So, I can't see what I'm doing wrong now, can anyone offer any suggestions or help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct except you should use capital `D` not small `d` in `do`:

```
console.log('_date', _date.format('dddd, Do MMMM YYYY'));
```

Difference between `Do` and `do` is:

- `do` is the index of the day in the week, for example if you check the calender you will find 1st October is Thursday which is the 4th day of the week as the index start from 0 and if you changed to 2 October which is Friday it will give you 5th and same for 3 Oct => 6th and then the new week start from Sunday then 4 Oct => 0th and start over again.
- `Do` is the index of the day in the month and that what you expected the result to be, 1th Oct is 1th, 2nd Oct => 2nd and so on.

Check the [docs](http://momentjs.com/) here for more info

Comment: Just a heads-up, your `Do` and `do` is the wrong way around in your examples btw.

Comment: Thanks @dooburt fixed :)